# Converting google maps api v2 to v3 getting script error in main.js

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am converting my code from version 2 to version 3. I am getting script error in 
http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/12/9/main.js
My code on the page is as

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&key=<%=strGk%>"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
            var myOptions = {
            zoom: 7,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            center: "<%=strOrig%>",
            mapTypeControl: true,
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM
            },
            navigationControl: true,
            navigationControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.ZOOM_PAN,
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
            },
            scaleControl: true,
            scaleControlOptions: {
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
            }
        }

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("directions"));
        google.maps.event.addListener(directionsDisplay, "addoverlay", afterDir);
        google.maps.event.addListener(directionsDisplay, "error", handleErrors);
        //  geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
```

Comment: What's the error?  Also it would help to add all the JS code; you've truncated it part-way through your initialize function

Answer (score 0):

You are using the deprecated deprecated **Navigation control**

In V3 it is divided into separate Zoom and Pan controls. See [**documentation**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-positioning)

**TRY**

```
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 7,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.91913101970850, -4.650520),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM
    },
    panControl: true,
    panControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
    },
    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
        //style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
    },
    scaleControl: true,
    scaleControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
    },
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
                                mapOptions);
}
```